# Shared pointer from static function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to improve my coding by using smart pointers, and am currently trying to replace all old raw pointers in our legacy code-base at work with smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` & `std::shared_ptr`). I now have a case where a pointer is returned from a static function.

What will happen if I change this to a `std::shared_ptr` that will be created using `std::make_shared` and returned from the function?

Will the `ref-count` be able to reach 0 since one reference is stored inside the static function, or will it remain until the program exits?

Previous:

```cpp
static MyObject* MyClass::createPointer()
{
    return new MyObject();
}
```

Now:

```cpp
static std::shared_ptr<MyObject> MyClass::createSharedPointer()
{
    return std::make_shared<MyObject>();
}
```

Comment: You have to show us the exact code to get an exact/accurate answer. C++ is far too complicated to give an answer based on just a problem description. A code snippet would make your post more concise. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Share specifics.

Comment: @user12002570 I've added a code snipped of how the static function looks like.

Comment: ```In my mind it will not be cleaned up until the program exits```. No. It will be removed as soon as its ```ref-count``` reaches ```0```.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Exactly, and since the static function will exist until the program exits, the `ref-count` will never become 0.

Comment: You have misunderstood. The static function doesn’t hold a reference to the pointer `std::make_shared` created

Comment: Can you remove ```static``` from function? It seems un-necessary in what you showed.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon No? Will it be given to whatever `std::shared_ptr` that the return value will be assigned to?

Comment: side note, just slapping std::shared_ptr onto everything without design is overkill (and probably might lead to other problems like circular dependencies. Make sure you know when it is enough to return std::unique_ptr (that should be your second choice).

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: That's the wrong way around. This member function does not need `this`, therefore it should be `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. Modern C++ compiler will do [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) following your code pattern. It doesn't matter if it is a static function or not.

But for `std::shared_ptr`, it's required to assign it to something or ref-count will be 0 (destructing the object immediately).

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
struct MyObject
{
    MyObject(int i):member{i}{

    }
    ~MyObject(){
        std::cout << "MyObject#" << member << " destruct\n";
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<MyObject> createPointer(int i){
        return std::make_shared<MyObject>(i);
    }
    int member = 0;

   
};

static std::shared_ptr<MyObject> get_singleton_ptr(){
    static auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyObject>(3);
    return ptr;
}

MyObject& get_singleton_ref(){
    static auto ptr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(4);
    return *ptr;
}

int main() {
    MyObject::createPointer(1);

    auto ptr = MyObject::createPointer(2);

    get_singleton_ptr();

    get_singleton_ref();

    std::cout << "end program/scope\n";
}
```

The result should be

```
MyObject#1 destruct
end program/scope
MyObject#2 destruct
MyObject#4 destruct
MyObject#3 destruct
```

Comment: The logic of "destruct object immediately" is wrong. If your `shared_ptr` is not assigned to a variable, and instead is only a temporary, then the pointed-to object is destroyed _at the end of the full expression._. I.e. `std::cout << *( std::make_shared<int>(42));` is safe. The int object is not destroyed immediately, but only after it is printed.

Answer (score 5):

In the old code, there is a memory leak on the following condition:

```
static MyObject* MyClass::createPointer()
{
    return new MyObject(); /* <—- memory leak */
}
```

Do you eventually `delete` the `MyObject` you created? If the program ends and you don’t, then there will be a memory leak. It is not a `static` variable but a `dynamic` one so you are responsible for `delete`ing.

> In my mind it will not be cleaned up until the program exits

In the old code, it will not even be cleaned up until you clean it yourself.

In the new code:

```
static std::shared_ptr<MyObject> MyClass::createSharedPointer()
{
    return std::make_shared<MyObject>();
}
```

The smart pointer will handle `delete`ion for you so this is safe.

> Will the `ref-count` be able to reach *0* since one reference is stored inside the static function, or will it remain until the program exits?

There is no reference stored inside the static function. The static function doesn’t do anything differently from a non-static function in this case.

A function itself does not keep a reference count on the `std::shared_ptr` it creates. It is the `std::shared_ptr` that does this and this is an implementation detail.

Comment: In the old code, the pointer is being deleted, but that is beside the question I am asking. In regards to your question why it is a static function, I do not have an answer for you. It was written 15 years ago from someone that is probably retired by now.

Comment: I guess it had been tagged ```static``` because supposed not to be used somewhere else in entire project.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh I think they set it as `static` because they wanted to call the function without having to instantiate the object.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Back to my original question. Since the `std::make_shared` is made inside the static function, will the `ref_count` not reach 0 until the program exits?

Comment: @AndréLehto I am not that expert in this but I assume your ```static``` function only made the ```shared_ptr``` and all other ```usages``` of this memory, increment and decrement the ```ref-count```

Comment: No, a function itself does not keep a reference count on the `std::shared_ptr` it creates. So the static function itself will not have any effect on the reference count of the `std::shared_ptr` it created.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Would you like to create a comment clarifying this and I will mark it as the solution?

Comment: I assume you will upvote also :). Okay it’s about `std::shared_ptr` and how the smart pointer handles reference counting to know when to `delete` the dynamically allocated variable it points to. When an `std::shared_ptr` is created, it keeps a reference count of **0**. Whenever it gets copied, it increments this reference count and whenever it goes out of scope, it decrements this reference count. If the reference count is 0 and it goes out of scope, it `deletes` the memory it pointed to.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon: You've got the `static` logic the wrong way around. You mark a function `static` if it only uses `static` class members and no object members (or `this->`). This function is so simple that it uses only the constructor. That does not require an object instance; in fact a constructor is how you create a new object instance.

Comment: @MSalters I understand all this which is why I asked the OP to begin with. From the conversations we had so far in the comments, you will see that we pointed these out. The OP says *”I do not have an answer for you. It was written 15 years ago from someone that is probably retired by now.”* at first I thought it was done for internal linkage but the OP pointed out that the function is a member function.